# Wierd mongoose / mongodb behavior

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Why is it that in mongoose (OR mongodb maybe) Boolean `false` is not saved in the database but they are present in the result.

Mongoose schema:
`fav : { type: Boolean, default: false }`

Now if I mark it as true (via form input) , then only it is stored in the database otherwise it is not saved if it is 'undefined' (if not checked in form).

But if I fetch that field then it will output appropriate result as expected.
i.e if fav is `true` then 'true' else `false`.

The problem is that if I want to query for all the docs where `fav` is false then I just get empty an array returned because when the value is false then that field (`fav`) is not saved in the database, 
But I can easily query for `fav`==true because they are saved in the database.

Comment: MongoDB stores `false` in the database. If what you're vaguely describing is actually happening, it must be because of what mongoose sends. Try setting debugging to true and looking at what the actual insert is.

Comment: If I don't tick 'fav' input in the form then it is set to 'undefined' which is understood and that is why I've set the default option to false. But it is not setting the default if it is 'undefined' which is weird. I want it to mark as false if it is undefined.

Comment: Then it is saving `undefined` in MongoDB, which will be saved as `null`, which is a different value than `false`. Add some logic to save `false` instead of `undefined`. I guess it might be considered an error for Mongoose to count `undefined` as type Boolean.

Comment: It is the wrong approach to blame the technology if sth doesn't work as intended. Please show us your code. And since you were talking of ticking sth: in case we are talking of a HTML forms checkbox, the value simply isn't send if not ticked, hence it is undefined in JS and saved as null in MongoDb. But this tells me that you are saving the form directly to MongoDB, which is very bad practise. You should normalize and sanitize all user input before saving.